# jQuery: How do I select only one element from multiple with the same class?

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to have two divs, `.before-cart` and `.after-cart`, appear when a user clicks on the button `.slide-button`.

HTML:

```
<div class="before-cart"></div>
<a href="" class="slide-button"></a>
<div class="after-cart"></div>
```

Somewhat working jQuery:

```
$('.col-full').on('click', '.slide-button', function() {
  $('.before-cart, .after-cart').css('visibility', 'visible');    
});
```

When a user selects `.slide-button` above, every element with that class is selected.

I've gotten as far as to recognize that `$(this)` will probably solve my problem, however, I'm having trouble rewriting the jQuery so that `.before-cart`, and `.after-cart` are somehow contained within the `.slide-button`'s function. This is the closest I've gotten, which does not function as intended:

```
$('.slide-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.before-cart, .after-cart').css('visibility', 'visible');   
});
```

Comment: `closest()` finds ancestors, maybe you are looking for `find()` which finds descendants?

Comment: @connexo, I edited the post to provide a little more context, '.before-cart' and 'after-cart' are not dependents of '.slide-button'.

Comment: It's the `next()` and `previous()` elements, so `$(this).next('.after-cart')` for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would target the container with closest targeting the closest container that both before-cart and after-cart are children of and then use find() to target the specific classes. This way you can use $(this) confortably.

Good luck

```js
$('.slide-button').on('click', function(){
  //$(this).closest('.before-cart, .after-cart').css('visibility','visible');   
  $(this).closest(".container").find(".before-cart, .after-cart").toggle();
  
  // can also use .show() or .hide() if you dont want to toggle
});
```

```css
.before-cart{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.after-cart{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.container{
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  height: 50px;
}

.slide-button{
 float: left; 
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="before-cart">before</div>
  <button class="slide-button">SlideButton</button>
  <div class="after-cart">after</div>    
</div>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="before-cart">before</div>
  <button class="slide-button">SlideButton</button>
  <div class="after-cart">after</div>    
</div>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="before-cart">before</div>
  <button class="slide-button">SlideButton</button>
  <div class="after-cart">after</div>    
</div>
```